# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: dot (.)

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery script that goes like this:

```
$('.' + ajax_object.cartclass).on('click','a.add',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // get closest parent div 
        var cpd = $(this).closest('div.cartpn');
        cpd.addClass('code');
```

...

The `'.'` seems to be the problem for some reason, I keep geetting the syntax error because of it.

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .

Any idea why?

Comment: What is the value of `ajax_object.cartclass`? A string like `"..foo"` will throw the same exception.

Comment: Please finish your title

Comment: it wont add a dot in the title. I added it with brackets.

Comment: The error message means that `ajax_object.cartclass` is empty.

Comment: no it isn't, and everything works, it's value is "maindiv". That is not the issue, it has the proper value.

Comment: Are you really *really* sure? If you add `console.log( ajax_object.cartclass )` right before that line you see its value in the console?

Comment: the q has been answered (though i can't accept the answer just yet).

Comment: oh my goodness are you for real? it wasn't empty just the object wasn't declared beforehand. everything worked it's just the error bugged me.

Comment: "Not declared" == empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `ajax_object.cartclass` is properly defined.

```
var ajax_object = {};
ajax_object.cartclass = "testing"; // The class you're trying to listen to.
```

Your code should work properly after that, assuming you have a defined element of class `ajax_object.cartclass` which contains an `a` element of class `add`:

```
<div class="testing"><a class="add">Test this</a></div>
```

The following should now work:

```
$('.' + ajax_object.cartclass).on('click','a.add',function(e)
{
   console.log("hey"); // Console will output "hey" now.
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Your code should work fine after that.

Here's a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tyem0gs5/2/).

Comment: that's it, nice one! var ajax_object = {}; cleaned the error (though the code worked regardless).